# Get position of the address bar on iOS 15 devices

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ios15, address-bar

On iPhones with iOS 15, the address bar is at the bottom of the screen (default) or optionally at the top of the screen.

Is there any way to determine the position (bottom or top) of the address bar with JS?

Answer (score -2):

## Short Answer: No

### Explanation:

The reason that you cannot find the location of the address bar is because it is outside of the website.

What this means:

The website is one container, and **JS** can only assess things inside of the website container. The address bar is another container.

[image: Diagram]

### So why does this exist?

This is here to stop malicious websites from accessing your address bar (or something else) and typing in a link. At first you might think this is the same as a redirect, but it doesn't stop at the address bar. What if it had the ability to change your settings and auto download something?

### What are the workarounds?

You can display a prompt for the user to ask where the address bar is, however, there really isn't much you can do.

If you can tell us the reason for wanting to location, maybe we can find a workaround!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However, after trying around for another while, I figured out, that it really seems to be possible. On the iPhone 13 Pro as follows: If the address bar is at the bottom, the window.innerHeight is 664 or 745 (address bar collapsed). If the address bar is at the top these values are 663 or 733 respectively.

Comment: However, I don't know how to generalize this to other iPhone models (I don't have the corresponding data). Moreover, I don't know, how reliable this is (664 VS 663 is only one pixel difference) and whether there are some "split screen" settings or similar changing these data. Maybe somebody can help me to generalize this solution.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll work on a solution.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The position of the address bar being above or below could be exposed without there being any issue of anyone modifying the address bar.